"Login failed" with odbc_connect (raw) connection string; works with pyodbc
The following pyodbc connection works fine:
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
conn = pyodbc.connect(Driver='SQL Server',
                      Server='some_server_address,1433',
                      Database='some_db',
                      UID ='some_user',
                      PWD = 'some_password')

cursor = conn.cursor()
df = pd.read_sql_query('''select top 100 * from tableA''', conn)
cursor.close()
conn.close()

When I try the same with SQLalchemy it fails
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import sqlalchemy as sa
    
connection_string = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=some_server_address,1433;DATABASE=some_db;UID=some_user;PWD=some_password"
connection_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})
engine = create_engine(connection_url)
conn = engine.connect()

with the following error:
InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'some_user'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'some_user'. (18456)")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/rvf5)

How can I fix it?
Update
As suggested below I tried
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
connection_string = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=some_server_address,1433;DATABASE=some_db;UID=some_user;PWD=some_password"
conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
    
cursor = conn.cursor()
df = pd.read_sql_query('''select top 100 * from tableA''', conn)
cursor.close()
conn.close()

Everything worked perfectly

What happens if you pass the connection_string value (which fails for SQLAlchemy) directly to pyodbc.connect() ?

@GordThompson, It worked, I posted an update.

What version of SQLAlchemy are you using? Does your password (or any other value in the connection string) contain punctuation characters like ;, {, }, [, ], &, +, etc.?

@GordThompson, SQLAlchemy version = 2.0.25. There are /,=,+ in password

You have encountered a bug in SQLAlchemy. It has been reported here:
https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/11250
As a workaround, you can use individual kwargs with URL.create(), similar to what you did for .pyodbc.connect():
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine(
    sa.URL.create(
        "mssql+pyodbc",
        username="howie",
        password="ab+cd",
        host="192.168.0.199",
        port=1433,
        database="test",
        query=dict(driver="SQL Server")
    )
)


When I initially ran a similar query with pandas.to_sql() based on your suggestion, I got an "Invalid precision value (0)" error with my sample dataframe. After changing the driver to "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server" it worked!  This should be the default method for connecting to MSSQL from Python running on a Windows machine. Most people suggest formatting the connection string with the combination of db_params = quote_plus(conn_str)
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(db_params)), which did not work for me!
